# php sql insert command not working

Tags: php, sql

This is the code I am using to insert code into sql but not functions .Any help please!!

This is the entire code.The same insert query command is working with other parts of the code except here and I am pretty puzzled and i also don't have any error message.

```
<?php
require_once 'core/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['accept'])){
$response = array();


//Pass your driver number here
$id = $_POST['id'];
$accept=$_POST['accept'];




//Get user id of the driver
//As the conceptAssignments have the driverNo instead of the user id, we need to get the user id
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE texirequest SET accept ='$accept' where id = '$id'");


    if($result){
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Data Update successful.";

// payment update
//Data





        }else{
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Could not load data".mysql_error();
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
}else{

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);



}

                            $phone = "88";
                            $namec = "jj";
                            $named = "dd"; 
                            $amount="50";
                            $fuel="fff";
                            $did="50";
                            $reg="gg";
                            $mail="d@g";
$maild="d@t";
                            echo $phone;
                            echo $name;
$status= "pending";
echo $status;
$sql="INSERT INTO pay ( namec,mailc,did,named,maild,phone,fuel,vno,total,status)".
    "VALUES ('".$name."', '".$mail."', '".$did."', '".$named."', '".$maild."', '".$phone."', '".$fuel."', '".$reg."', '".$amount."', '".$status."');";
echo $sql;

?>
```

Comment: "Not working" Is?..

Comment: Where did you query databse  with insert statement?

Comment: i have two files that connect the database

Comment: What 'not working' means? Which error do you see?

Comment: @Andrew data isn't  being inserted

Comment: ca you post enitere code, with mysqli_query() and so on...

Comment: It's nonsense. Insert always add row. Only reason for data isn't inserted is sql exception. What exception you receive? Add code example how you are executing query. What php extensions is it? MySQL/MySQLi? PostgreSQL? PDO? Question now is very poor quality and may be closed.

Comment: @Andrew To be more specific the code is to insert data into my sql .And similar insertion queries are working perfect  except this.On top of it there is no error also.

Comment: There is no query execution in your code. Are you missing `mysql_query($sql)` ?

Comment: @Andrew no these are just static values i assigned to the variables if this works then i have to add the query

Comment: What are you expecting? No query, but data must be added? That looks strange.

Comment: the query is already defined in the db_connect.php

Comment: @ Andrew Thanks for the clue.I really forgot mentioning the query execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO pay ( namec,mailc,did,named,maild,phone,fuel,vno,total,status)".
    "VALUES ( '{$name}','{$mail}',{$did},'{$named}','{$maild}','{$phone}','{$fuel}','{$reg}',{$amount},'{$status}')";

//Check query  
echo $sql;
```

Comment: output of echo $sql is (INSERT INTO pay ( namec,mailc,did,named,maild,phone,fuel,vno,total,status)VALUES ( 'jj','d@g',50,'dd','d@t','88','fff','gg',50,'pending'))

Comment: Try execute query in MySQL terminal

Answer (score 0):

Without more information like error messages I can only suggest this query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pay ( namec, mailc, did, named, maild, phone, fuel, vno, total, status) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$mail."', '".$did."', '".$named."', '".$maild."', '".$phone."', '".$fuel."', '".$reg."', '".$amount."', '".$status."');";
```

Maybe run:

```
echo mysqli_error($link);
```

This should tell you more about what is wrong with the query

Comment: can you be more specific then about what is not workung? Do you get no result, is the result not the one you want, is something missing, Does the script crash or what

Comment: By not working I mean the data is not being inserted into my database.

Comment: unfortunately no.That is why i am confused

Comment: Hm, that is odd. Neither http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php nor http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.errno.php give you any information?
Where do you execute the statement anyway?

Comment: This is actually a part of webservice for a mobile app.And once i load this code i am reloading the page on browser

Comment: For testing purposes can you call die() before you relod to read the error? Or look in the error.log or ooutput potentiel error or query results. But since this is php you have to call mysqli_query at some point or another way of sending the query to the database...

Comment: I am not so versed with the code can you give me a code hint.

Comment: How are we supposed to know how this code works if you do not know it all by yourself... Can you tell what is inside the db_connect.php?

Comment: Actually i doesn,t know in the sense i cannot do it as a pro.But the code must actually insert values that are sent from the user.but to test the insertion i had to declare static variables.But this did not help.

Comment: do you know how to execute a query?

Comment: Yes this query with other tables is working except with this and it is even working with the terminal

Answer (score 0):

```
$Sql = "INSERT INTO `pay`  (`namec`,`mailc`,`did`,`named`,`maild`,`phone`,`fuel`,`vno`,`total`,`total`)     VALUES('$name','$mail','$did','$named','$maild','$phone','$fuel','$reg','$amount','$status')";
```

// HERE Your SEND The Value Into the Data, $Database is the variable contain the connection of the database

```
$result = $Database->query($sql);   
if($result == true){
 echo "success";
}else{
 echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: But this did not echo anything

Comment: @MurthyVaranasi Can You Get Some Error

Comment: I am though not completely new to coding but still a fresher.If you can help me with the error command i will do.

Comment: @MurthyVaranasi Send Me Your Database Name ?

Comment: versogeo_fog-Database Name

Answer (score 0):

The point I missed was adding query execution.The code that worked was

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO pay ( namec,mailc,did,named,maild,phone,fuel,vno,total,status)".
    "VALUES ( 'name','$mail','$did','$named','$maild','$phone','$fuel','$reg','$amount','$status')");
```

Thanks for the support .